# Error: field integrity exception: unknown (required must not be specified)

Tags: metadata, ant, migration-tool

Got the following error when tried to deploy metadata via ant migration tool

`Error: field integrity exception: unknown (required must not be specified)`

[image]

Field metadata configuration is the following:

```
  <fields>
    <fullName>Description__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Description</label>
    <length>1000</length>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>LongTextArea</type>
    <visibleLines>3</visibleLines>
  </fields>
```

Answer (score 5):

Bit of an old question, but since there's no answer yet, I'll post my experience. 
I got the same message when I tried to deploy a field from sandbox A to sandbox B. The field was named Nationality__c, and at the beginning it was already present in both sandboxes as a required Text field. Then, in sandbox A, we changed the definition of the field to a picklist (which can not be required). Now, trying to deploy to sandbox B failed, with the mentioned error message.

The solution is to uncheck the "Required" checkbox on the existing field in sandbox B before deploying.